# How to get nearby users and distances?

Tags: laravel, geolocation

First I want to show you the current database structure. There are two tables:

**users**

- id
- name
- location_id

**locations**

- id
- city
- lat
- lng

Now I want to implement an API which gets the nearby users and their distance. Like nearby users:

```
{{name:user1,distance:5km},(name:user2,distance:7 km)}
```

Comment: You can implement stored procedure in database to calculate distance, then select records with conditions and ordering, like closest not more then 5km. If you use PostgreSQL - watch this http://postgis.net/

Comment: Agree with @ineersa , you certainly can do that as well in Transact SQL. Now the real question is how often and what are the numbers of users you have as it might take some time to compute.  Depending on that you might want to implement a table to store this information.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this

**User Model**

```
public function location(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Location');
}
```

In Location model create a function name `rsine` and then create a local scope named with `scopeIsWithinMaxDistance` like this

**Location Model**

```
/**
 * Scope for adding distance filter
 */
public function scopeIsWithinMaxDistance($query, $rsine, $radius = 5)
{
    return $query->selectRaw("*, {$rsine} AS distance")
                 ->whereRaw("{$rsine} < ?", [$radius])
                 ->orderBy('distance');
}

/**
 * Sql command for finding distance between 2 coordinates
 */
public static function rsine($coordinates)
{
    return '(6371 * acos(cos(radians(' . $coordinates['latitude'] . ')) 
    * cos(radians(`lat`)) 
    * cos(radians(`lng`) 
    - radians(' . $coordinates['longitude'] . ')) 
    + sin(radians(' . $coordinates['latitude'] . ')) 
    * sin(radians(`lat`))))';
}

public static function convertKMToMiles($dist)
{
    return $dist * 1.609344;
}
```

Now call it in controller

```
$coordinates = ['latitude' => '28.392200', 'longitude' => '77.320801'];

$rsine = Location::rsine($coordinates);

$radius = Location::convertKMToMiles(5); //convert KM to miles

$users = User::with(['location' => function ($query) use ($rsine) {
               $query->selectRaw("*, {$rsine} AS distance");
         }])->whereHas('location', function ($query) use ($radius, $rsine) {
               $query->isWithinMaxDistance($rsine, $radius);
         })->get();
```

Now you can print it like this

```
foreach($users as $user){
   $user->name;
   $user->location->city;
   $user->location->distance;
}
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use ..........

Comment: you need to change `radians(`latitude`)` to `radians(`lat`)` and `radians(`longitude`)` to `radians(`lng`)` in `rsine` method  
because you have `lat` and `lng` fields in your locations table. Updated answer check it

Comment: I tried below code too:    public static function rsine($coordinates)
{
    return Location::select('id', DB::raw(' 6371 * acos( cos( radians(' . $coordinates['latitude'] . ') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(' . $coordinates['longitude'] . ') ) + sin( radians(' . $coordinates['latitude'] . ') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) )  as distance'))->get();
}

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters (SQL: select *, *, [{\"distance\":10723.218919804329},{\"distance\":1285.513973341391},{\"distance\":1284.2498526350137}] AS distance from `locations` where `users`.`location_id` = `locations`.`id` and [{\"distance\":10723.218919804329},{\"distance\":1285.513973341391},{\"distance\":1284.2498526350137}] > 8.04672 order by `distance` asc)",

Comment: use same as in my answer don't try to put `return Location::select` in `rsine` method and also put  ` in  radians(`lat`) and then try. It is a working code, i have used it in project